# Teechart Axis scrollbar tool

Tags: activex, teechart

I can see a new tool axis scrollbar in the Teechart 2015 activeX, The issue is when I open the TeeChartDefines.h it doesn't have any tc number related to this tool, Also there are no header file and CPP file for the same.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are experiencing is a Feature Request. We have already added it in [TeeChart Activex bugzilla tracker](http://bugs.teechart.net/describecomponents.cgi?product=ActiveX%20) to consider its inclusion for upcoming versions. Here's the link http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1237

Feel free to add your email to the tickets so you can be automatically notified when an update arrives.